# WebStorm - node.js remote debugger breakpoints won't work

Tags: node.js, webstorm, remote-debugging

I'm remote debugging a node.js process via WebStorm (running on MacOS 10.12.6).

I'm attaching to the process successfully (I know this because I run node with `--debug-brk` and then the process suspends until I resume it in WebStorm), however there is no indication that the breakpoints are attached (of course they also don't work - the code in the breakpoint line is running but the breakpoint isn't suspending the process).

Few notes:

1. The breakpoint is enabled and "Suspend" is checked.
2. Local debugging works fine
3. Don't know if it's related by I tried to switch this registry: `js.debugger.v8.use.any.breakpoint` on/off and there was no change.

This is the command I use to run the node:

```
node --debug-brk=5858  server.js
```

Anybody has an idea?

Comment: What are WebStorm and Node.js versions?

Comment: Webstorm 2017.2(build 172.3317.70) node version 4.4.7

Comment: just tried debugging with exactly same Node version - works as expected (checked in 2017.2.1, but I don't think it should make a difference). Is your app running on a same host, or on a different machine/VM/container? Do you use sourcemaps in your project, or is it a raw javascript, not bundled/transpiled/minified/etc.?

Comment: My app is running on a VM(centOS 7), when I run remote debug to my local machine it works fine. The javascript is in a raw form.

Comment: Do you use a proxy or port forwarding (as Node.js debugging is only listening on localhost - see http://delog.wordpress.com/2011/04/08/a-simple-tcp-proxy-in-node-js/, for example)?